# Post a file to AWS from a credentialed client in Python

Tags: python, post, https, amazon-web-services, boto

I am writing a client application to post a file to our S3 instance, but I am not getting any response and the file is not posting when using the code below. It works by hitting our server for credentials, the details are then used by the client to connect to our s3 instance (or would be if this was working) and uploads the file.

```
import httplib, urllib, json

setup_headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.server.address")
conn.request("GET", "/api/data/upload-request/", '', setup_headers)

response = conn.getresponse()

response_data = response.read()
print response_data

aws_setup = json.loads(response_data)

aws_setup.update({'filename':'fname.zip', 'file': open('fname.zip', 'rb').read()})

aws_params = urllib.urlencode(aws_setup)
aws_headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
aws_conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("address.s3.amazonaws.com")
aws_conn.request("POST", "", aws_params, aws_headers)

aws_conn.close()
conn.close()
```

What is returned from the initial connection request object:

```
{"AWSAccessKeyId": "correct key", "success_action_redirect": "http://our.web.address/api/upload-success/", "acl": "private", "key": "${filename}", "signature": "signature", "policy": "encoded policy", "Content-Type": "application/zip"}
```

This was failing due to problems with the multi-part form data. The new issue I am running into is that I'm getting an error in encode_multipart_formdata. If I pass in a file type object, it will attempt a string join which will fail. If I pass in a string, it obviously won't pull in the file contents, and I don't want to read the entire file contents into memory to pass. Code and both error reports are below:

```
import httplib
import json
import mimetypes

def post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files):
    """
    Post fields and files to an http host as multipart/form-data.
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return the server's response page.
    """
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Content-Type': content_type
        }
    h.request('POST', selector, body, header)
    res = h.getresponse()
    return res.status, res.reason, res.read()

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    for key, value in fields.iteritems():
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body

def get_content_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'

setup_headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("our.server.address")
conn.request("GET", "/api/data/upload-request/", '', setup_headers)

response = conn.getresponse()

response_data = response.read()

aws_setup = json.loads(response_data)
status, reason, data = post_multipart("address.s3.amazonaws.com", "", aws_setup, [['upload_file.zip', 'upload_file.zip', open("upload_file.zip")]])
print status
print reason
print data
conn.close()
```

The error with the file type object as shown in the code above:

```
TypeError: sequence item 32: expected string or Unicode, file found
```

Error when a string is pass in instead:

```
400
Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><RequestId>9AA6411E13792EC6</RequestId><HostId>EkkcNUkIWIVk8wbhEplhp0L+Rqsa089TD0VusgMUQsQJo3rUUf/zbP+k67fEzolc</HostId></Error>
```

Doing this with boto (which I got to work) required having our private key visible to the client-side.

Comment: I highly recommend sticking with `boto` for something like this.  Could you elaborate on why this required making the private key visible?  It shouldn't..

Comment: You are urlencoding a file object rather than the contents of the file... that may not be what you intended?

Comment: @gabrtv every example I've seen of the boto S3Connection object requires an access key, and the secret access key. Since that connection would be created by the client, it would have that secret access key locally unless I'm misreading the documentation and there is another way to use boto for the connection.

Comment: @Jjensen.mike You should check out http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/ The general idea is that you can calculate a signature and include that as part of the upload form.  Computing a valid signature requires your secret key, but does not expose it.

Comment: @gabrtv That's what I have been doing in the example code I provided above, but the file upload still is not going through

Comment: @DrSkippy That was probably one issue, I changed it to ".read()" but this hasn't fully resolved the issue

Comment: @Jjensen.mike Are you sure you're submitting the POST?  Can you add an `aws_conn.getresponse()` followed by a `response.read()` and provide the response code, status and body from the POST?

Comment: @Jjensen.mike I see the response for the GET request in the code sample, but not the response from the POST.  You seem to call `aws_conn.close()` before you get the response.  Without a response code/status/body it's very hard to continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, try reading the response from the POST and dumping it out somewhere.  That should give a clue about what is failing.  Are you using boto on the server to generate the POST data that is returned? Or are you using your own code?  If it's your own code, have you tried comparing your POST data to that generated by boto?

Comment: @gabrtv You both were correct, the post request was invalid for multi-part form data. I fixed that and tried another recipe but am still having problems, any suggestions you all have would be super helpful. I detailed what I did in the updated post above

Comment: If you are doing the upload from an EC2 instance, you might want to consider using IAM Roles. You can create a JSON policy that grants only the rights needed to do the upload and then associate this policy with an IAM Role. That role can then be associated with your instance at launch time.  And the credentials on the instance are then automatically rotated every few hours. I think it's a great way to securely get credentials on to an EC2 instance.